# effective degree for normalized escape-time of hybrids

Tags: fractals, complex-dynamics

In [Renormalizing the Mandelbrot Escape](http://linas.org/art-gallery/escape/escape.html), Linas Vepstas derives the normalized (smooth, continuous) escape-time formula for the exterior of the Mandelbrot set.  On the page is also written:

> **Iterating Different Equations**
>   The above formulas apply only to the Mandelbrot iterate. Other iterates require modified equations. The corresponding results are easy to get. If the iterated equation is of the form
>   $$Z_n = Z_{n-1} ^ p + O(Z_{n-1}^{p-1})$$
>   where $p$ is the highest power of $Z$ occurring in the iterated equation, then
>   $$\mu = n + 1 - \frac{\log (\log  |Z_n|)}{\log p}$$

where $|Z_n| \ge R \gt |Z_{n-1}|$ for $R$ a sufficiently large escape radius.

I am interested in "hybrid" formulas, where (for example) the formula alternates between $z \to z^2 + c$ and $z \to z^3 + c$ at each iteration step (so the two-step iteration formula is $z \to (z^2+c)^3+c$).  Here the power $p$ for use in the formula for $\mu$ must be somewhere between $2$ and $3$, but I'm not sure how to reach the exact value.  The power for the two-step formula is $6$, I suspect the average might be $\sqrt{6} \approx 2.45$ but I'm not sure how to justify it.

**Question:** given a hybrid of $m$ formulae whose large-$z$ behaviour approximate $z \to z^{p_k}$ for $2 \le p_k \in \mathbb{N}$, what is the correct way to take an average power $p=f_p(p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_m)$ for use in the formula for $\mu$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that instead of alternating, that instead, you just took the two-steps, and counted that as a single-step.  Then, in this example, $p=6$, as you point out. For the purpose of counting until you escape, its sufficient to iterate the two-steps, and count those -- you get the same results as counting alternating single-steps, except that your count is half as large.  And that gives you the clue to the desired answer: if the two-step count gives

$$\mu_{twostep}=n_{twostep}−\frac{\log(\log|Z_n|)}{\log 6}$$

then the single-step count must be twice this:

$$\mu_{altstep}=n_{altstep}−2\frac{\log(\log|Z_n|)}{\log 6}$$

since, in general, either $n_{altstep} = 2n_{twostep}$ or $n_{altstep} = 2n_{twostep}+1$ -- and, for large counts, the extra 1 should not matter: it disappears as long as the escape radius is large. And you may as well take the escape radius to be large: a few billion, or even 1e20 - the extra steps taken to get to this radius cost a very small amount of extra cpu time (a few percent, typically), especially for deep zooms.

The other way to look at this is that you replaced $\log p$ by $\frac{\log p}{2}$ .. but well, golly:

$$\frac{\log p}{2} = \log\sqrt p$$

so your guess was right, and that is the reason that it works. In general: $\log p^a = a\log p$.

For the general case, take $p=p_1+p_2+\cdots+p_m$ and count m-steps. Alternately count single-steps, and use $p_{single}=p^{1/m}$

I'm assuming that you always rigorously alternate every step. If not: if you only alternate sometimes, then you will have to keep track of a running average.  The "obvious" way to count would then be to "cnt += p_k" if you took the k'th alternate, and adjust accordingly.

Comment: I found that a per-pixel running average method gave discontinuities/seams between iteration bands with some colouring methods; using a per-image power worked better.